# How to solve mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda3 error /dev/sda3 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!?

Tags: linux, archlinux, partition

I am trying to install Arch Linux on a VM in my windows pc

The Installation guide on the arch website doesn't say how to make the partitions, So I used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPYfoFSXB9A) tutorial to do so,
[image: A GPT partition type with a efi, swap, and linux root x86-64]

but when I tried to format these with `# mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda3`  for mounting I get

`/dev/sda3 is apparently in use by the system; will not make filesystem here!`

`# mkfs.fat -F 32 /dev/sda1` gives me

`# mkfs.fat: unable to open /dev/sda1 :Device or resource busy`

Comment: That's not a programming question, rather ask on superuser.com. Make sure you read their guidelines first though!

Comment: Right I will do that should I delete this also there are some related questions here too?

Comment: Superuser wont let me post because I made a post within 40 minutes (I never even had a superuser account prior to this) but wont let me post with a picture either cuz I don't have 10 reputation which I have here on stackoverflow what is happening???!!!!

Comment: I'm honestly not sure, but I know that SO and related sites from the stackexchange network do limit new user activity. This is a safeguard against spambots, I assume. Sorry that it hits you. That said, it could be that you can migrate this question to superuser instead, though I'm not sure how.